# IdentityServer4 login and users in a web application

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I'm creating the user authentication in a web application, and I want to use Identity Server for resource protection.

The sample code and documentation shows how the user logs into Identity Server after creating an account for it. That is to say, they log in with their own Identity Server account. The quickstart even provides a UI.

But I don't want users of my application to have to log in to Identity Server, an external website. I want them to only have to log in to the web application.

So how to proceed? It just doesn't seem at all clear from the documentation how you're supposed to handle this scenario, which I would have thought would be the most common.

Do I just use a pre-defined API scope and user for token validation, holding for all the website's users? That doesn't seem to be very secure given that any user of the website or anyone with the client name and secret would have a valid token. Not sure what the point is in having the security if it's that easily worked around.

Or do I interact with my Identity Server instance somehow after the user is registered in the web application, and store the new user in a database? I can't find any mention of this in the documentation . It all seems to be very muddled to be honest.

Please could anybody shed light on some of this? What is the "standard" approach here? To have the user sign in to the external Identity Server website? That seems a great way to annoy your users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one application and you don't intend to add more applications that needs to share users, then you should look at [ASP.NET Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

The whole point with OpenID-Connect/IdentityServer is to delegate the managing and handling of users/passwords (authentication) to a central entity. So individual applications don't need to deal with that complexity. IdentityServer is useful when you have multiple applications or if you have more complex integration needs. It is also perfect if you need to customize it to your own needs. If you don't need the customization part you can also outsource it to someone else like [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) that give you an IdentityServer like experience as a service.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That does help explain. Unfortunately this is not made at all clear in the documentation. I suspect the whole thing is just people confusing themselves in all honesty. There's got to be an easier way to just have centralised authentication and a token in one's headers.

Comment: It's all about security and keeping the users safe and the user-credentials safe. Today you expect that you can login with your Google/Twitter/FB/GitHub accout to most applications (mobile/web...) but at the same time i would never trust those applications to have my real google username/passwords. So with open-connect you always open a new window and you do that authentication without letting the application see my secret password. If you only need machine-to-machine communication (no users involved) then openid-connect have defined a client credential flow.